# uploading files to onedrive for business using delphi rest api

Tags: delphi, onedrive

1.I am able get an authorization code.
 2.I am able to Redeem the authorization code for tokens.
 3.I am able to Discover the OneDrive for Business resource URI by opening the
   service end point link in the browser with sign in another tab.
 4. Make a request to the OneDrive API(Here am getting unauthorized exception even though i  succesfully completed above steps.

Redeem refresh token for an access token to call OneDrive API

```
edt_OneDrive_AuthCode := '';
edt_OneDrive_AccessToken := '';
edt_OneDrive_RefreshToken := '';
edt_OneDrive_ClientID:='*************************************';
edt_AzureTenant_ID:='****************************' ;


//edt_OneDrive_RedirectURI:= 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'; // ??

edt_OneDrive_RedirectURI:= 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/';
edt_OneDrive_Resource:='https://api.office.com/discovery/';

LURL := 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize';
LURL := LURL + '?response_type=' + URIEncode('code');
LURL := LURL + '&client_id=' + URIEncode(edt_OneDrive_ClientID);
LURL := LURL + '&redirect_uri=' + URIEncode(edt_OneDrive_RedirectURI);
//LURL := LURL + '&resource=' + URIEncode(edt_OneDrive_Resource);
//https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}

///1.Log in and get an authorization code
 wv := Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.Create(self);
try
  wv.OnTitleChanged := self.OAuth2_OneDrive_BrowserTitleChanged;
  wv.ShowModalWithURL(LURL);
finally
  wv.Release;
end;


//Step 2: Redeem the authorization code for tokens
RESTClient:=TRESTClient.Create(nil);
RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/********-****-****-****-************/oauth2/token';

RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
RESTRequest.Client:=   RESTClient;
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('client_id', edt_OneDrive_ClientID, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('redirect_uri',edt_OneDrive_RedirectURI , TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('grant_type', 'authorization_code', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('resource', 'https://api.office.com/discovery/', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('code', edt_OneDrive_AuthCode, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('prompt', 'admin_consent', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest.Execute;


OAuth2_OneDrive:=TOAuth2Authenticator.Create(nil);

if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('access_token', LToken) then
     OAuth2_OneDrive.AccessToken := LToken;
if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('refresh_token', LToken) then
     OAuth2_OneDrive.RefreshToken := LToken;

 //STEP 3:Discover the OneDrive for Business resource URI
 //GET https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services
 //Authorization: Bearer {access_token}

{ RESTRequest.ClearBody;
 RESTRequest.Params.Clear;

 RESTClient:=TRESTClient.Create(nil);
 RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services';

 RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
 RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
 RESTRequest.Client:=   RESTClient;
 RESTRequest.AddAuthParameter('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + OAuth2_OneDrive.AccessToken, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER,[TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]);
 RESTRequest.Execute; }

 //Step 4. Redeem refresh token for an access token to call OneDrive API
 RESTRequest.ClearBody;
 RESTRequest.Params.Clear;

 RESTClient:=TRESTClient.Create(nil);
 RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/********-****-****-****-************/oauth2/token';

 RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
 RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
 RESTRequest.Client:=   RESTClient;
 RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('client_id', edt_OneDrive_ClientID, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
 RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('grant_type', 'refresh_token', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
 //RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('resource', 'https://api.office.com/discovery/', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
 RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('resource', 'https://comp14602-my.sharepoint.com/', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);

 RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('refresh_token',OAuth2_OneDrive.RefreshToken , TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
 RESTRequest.Execute;


 OAuth2_OneDrive:=TOAuth2Authenticator.Create(nil);

 if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('access_token', LToken) then
     OAuth2_OneDrive.AccessToken := LToken;
 if RESTRequest.Response.GetSimpleValue('refresh_token', LToken) then
     OAuth2_OneDrive.RefreshToken := LToken;
//Step 5. Make a request to the OneDrive API

 RESTRequest.ClearBody;
 RESTRequest.Params.Clear;

 RESTClient:=TRESTClient.Create(nil);

 RESTClient.BaseURL :='https://{tenant name here}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive';



 RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
 RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
 RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;


 RESTRequest.AddAuthParameter('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + OAuth2_OneDrive.AccessToken, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER,[TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]);

 RESTRequest.Execute;//Here am getting unauthorized exception
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but the URL you are requesting is wrong. It should be https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive. You shouldn't have the /me/ in the URL.

Comment: i tried below url's for all am getting unauthorized exception 1.comp14602-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/drive    2.comp14602-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/drive       3.comp14602-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive 4.comp14602-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive &first two links are working in browser with office365 signed in another tab.next two are working no where.If i compare requests in fiddler i can see the requests in browser are with cookies where as in my request from code there are no cookie